# Problema consulta TSQL por las comillas

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo una consulta en TSQL que no me esta funcionando dentro de un procedimiento almacenado, pero desde una pantalla de consultas si, tengo claro que debe ser un tema de los escapes de las comillas.
Pongo un pantallazo donde se ve claramente el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la consulta, esa la hace bien, pero si sustituyo lo que hay detras de `TipoPalanquillaLaminacion =` por `@Aux_Palan` devuelve 0.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Edit(1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro, porque el texto dentro de `@Aux_Palan` tiene comillas extra, ya que le estás agregando un `char(39)` al principio y al final, esos no son necesarios

Comment: Le he quitado los dos Char(39) que acompañan a @TipoPalanquilla y se comporta igual.

Comment: Entiendo que debe ser `WHERE TipoPalanquillaLaminacion = @Aux_Palan` sin comillas, es así como lo tienes?

Comment: Estas haciendo dos reemplazos diferentes y para colmo no son las mismas querys. chequea que las querys sean iguales. cuando haces char(39)+algo+char(39) queda un string que contiene unas comillas (como string) mas el char(39) adentro de eso.. no es lo mismo que lo que haces arriba, por la forma en que arma la cadena.. y no es lo que vos queres. si sacas el char(39) de tu segunda consulta deberia andar perfecto.

Comment: Si, teneis razon, no hacen falta las comillas, me he estado rayando un buen rato porque no habia manera, de estas veces que te quedas ofuscado y luego es una tonteria como una casa, gracias por la ayuda.